# NSMutableArray containsObject question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to compare two arrays, say array a is a series of arrays like so:

```
((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```

and array b is a series of array like so:

```
((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3))
```

How do I check if an item from array a is not within array b

```
for(NSString* itemFromA in a) {
 if ([b containsObject: itemFromA] == FALSE) { 
   NSLog(@"ok");
   break;
 }
}
```

this didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please take care to format your questions properly (format your code as such so it can be read). Also, it's not clear what you're asking because your description doesn't quite match your code. Your for loop makes it look like your arrays A and B contain NSString instances but your description suggests each is an array of arrays of something unidentified (a string? A number? An NSValue containing an NSRange struct?). Please clarify the exact structure.

Comment: You should *never* compare to *false*. Always use !. `![b containsObject:itemFromA]`. In the case of comparing to *false* it doesn't make a difference. What you're *not allowed to do*, is comparing to *true*. Btw: in Objective-C one uses *YES* and *NO* instead of *true* and *false*.

Comment: @Georg: While I agree with you on YES/NO for BOOL, <code>if ([b containsObject:itemFromA] == NO)</code> is perfectly valid. -containsObject: returns a BOOL, so it's like saying BOOL isThere = YES; if (isThere == NO)... which is the same as if (!isThere).

Comment: What kind of objects are in the arrays? Custom objects?

Comment: Simply put, this question cannot be answered with any confidence until Pruitlgoe clarifies the exact data structure.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Array A contains arrays, these arrays contain strings ("1", "1") and so forth. Array B is the same. So what I am trying to do is compare if the contents of a[0], which would be an array containing two strings, "1" and "1", is also within b. I'm coming to this from a PHP and AppleScript background - Georg, thanks for the heads up on the YES/NO - TRUE/FALSE clarification. In AppleScript you could easily do this by this line of code:    repeat with thisA in a
   if (b does not contain {contents of thisA}) then -->do something end if end repeat

Comment: Georg - just an aside I had used ! for my comparison rather than FALSE but since it wasn't delivering the results I was looking for I thought perhaps I was doing something wrong syntax wise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the iterator type is correct; It sounds like `b` and `a` are arrays of arrays, yet you are using `NSString*` as the iterator type. I'm not a whiz with Objective-C internals but I believe this will cause your checking to fail (as `itemFromA` will be of type `NSString*` and you are iterating through a collection of `NSArray*`s.)

In addition `containsObject:` may not be doing what you want, namely that it uses `isEqual` to perform the comparison. There is mention in the documentation that `isEqual` is specialized for `NSArray` but I could not find details as to that specialization. I don't know how `containsObject:` will fare in these kinds of "deep" comparison operations.

Comment: Because of the dynamic nature of Objective-C, even when specifing the wrong datatype the code calls the right method.

Comment: I don't think this matters at runtime since both NSArray and NSString are subclasses of NSObject, which holds the equality and hash methods. Since whatever's in the array will answer these with their own implementation, their behavior would be the same no matter what class you gave to hold the pointer. The issue is that we have no idea whatsoever what the exact structure is based on the question/code. That's what's important because, for example, NSArray's -isEqual: relies on different criteria than NSString's.

Comment: Indeed, the static type of the pointer doesn't determine what actual method implementation will be used - that will be determined at runtime by the dynamic type of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, though feel free to clean it up.

@implementation AppController
- (IBAction)GetArrayData:(id)sender {

```
int a=10;
int b=10;
int c=20;
int d=20;
int row=0;
int col=0;

NSMutableArray* e = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* f = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(row=0; row<a; row++) {
    for(col=0; col<b; col++) {
        NSNumber* thisrow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:row];
        NSNumber* thiscol = [NSNumber numberWithInt:col];
        [e addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:thisrow, thiscol, nil]];
    }
}

for(row=0; row<c; row++) {
    for(col=0; col<d; col++) {
        NSNumber* thisrow = [NSNumber numberWithInt:row];
        NSNumber* thiscol = [NSNumber numberWithInt:col];
        [f addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:thisrow, thiscol, nil]];

    }
}

//check to see if f contains items from e
for(NSString* thisset in f) {
    if ([e containsObject: thisset]) {
        NSLog(@"This set (%@) is already being used.", thisset);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"We can start the ad at these coordinates: %@", thisset);
        break;
    }
}
```

[e release];
[f release];
}
@end